# Can't delete from table after switch from logical to streaming replication

Tags: replication, postgresql-11, logical-replication

On my DEV server I tested logical replication, and return to streaming after that.

Now **wal_level = replica** and I have two slaves:

```
pid  |state     |application_name    |client_addr|write_lag      |flush_lag      |replay_lag     |sync_priority|sync_state|
-----|----------|--------------------|-----------|---------------|---------------|---------------|-------------|----------|
12811|streaming |db-slave1           |*.*.*.*    |00:00:00.000569|00:00:00.001914|00:00:00.001932|            0|async     |
25978|streaming |db-slave2           |*.*.*.*    |00:00:00.000568|00:00:00.001913|00:00:00.001931|            0|async     |
```

Now I created new table and insert one record. For example:

```sql
create table test_delete (
    id int
);

insert into test_delete values (1);

delete from test_delete where id = 1;
```

The table created and replicated to both slaves, but deletion query failed with error:

> SQL Error [55000]: ERROR: cannot delete from table "test_delete" because it does not have a replica identity and publishes deletes
> Hint: To enable deleting from the table, set REPLICA IDENTITY using ALTER TABLE.

So, I need help to restore status before switch lo logical replication and ability to delete from tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation I found solution. Despite the fact that `wal_level` has changed in postgres.conf all tables still appears in `pg_publication_tables`.
So for check publication status used:

```
select * from pg_publication_tables;
```

and for remove records:

```
drop publication <publication_name>;
```